# Passing a template variable as input to a hidden form input field

Tags: python, django

I have a template *index.html* which contains a table of data. At the end of each row data, there is an edit button which allows you to edit the column entries in that row.

Here is how my table is constructed in *index.html*:

```
<table style="width:300px">
            <tr>
                <td> Mailing List Name</td>
                <td> Mailing List Creation Date</td>
            </tr>

            {% for listEntry in lists %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ listEntry.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ listEntry.create_date }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="/list_edit" method="post">
                            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Edit" />
                            **Extra hidden input fields would be added here**
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {%endfor%}

        </table>
```

How can I pass variables defined in the `ListEntry` model as hidden input fields to a form?

Comment: are these django forms ?

Comment: @karthikr Yes they are.

Comment: then you can just override the form widget as `HiddenInput`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  <input name="{{ listEntry.someId }}" type="hidden" value="{{ listEntry.value }}" />
```

However if you have one `<form>` element per row, you need to give `submit` action a value based on which row it is too.